# How to remove the intro animation which appears during the load up of some Wordpress themes?

Tags: php, customization, images, themes

How do you find and delete the code which makes the loading animation at the very start of every page on many wordpress sites appear?

Sometimes the animation is a simple loading wheel gif image and sometimes it is a more elaborate animation with pulsing dots, or maybe dots rotating in a circle, etc.

Comment: I can't imagine there is a generic solution for that. Probably best not to use themes that are so slow that they require such a thing

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to check the parent element of the animation using the inspector tool. When you find the very parent of the element, say its class is .loading-screen, then you simply add the rule at the bottom of your main queued CSS file:

```
.loading-screen{
    display: none !important;
}
```